# How to check a value of integer type after its was declared without value

Tags: c

Lets say that I make a struct of 4 int's, and then I scanf for all those 4 int's.

How I can check if not for all the int's the user has entered a value?

I have tried using NULL but was searching around that found that its not suppose to work for an int type. So is there a way to check it?

Comment: Read the docs for scanf, especially the part about the return value. (Same for any and all I/O functions.)

Comment: scanf returns the amount of successful formats, so just `if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4) < 4) { /* at least 1 int was formatted incorrectly */ }`.

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `scanf` ??

Comment: ***Always*** check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). Better yet, forget that `scanf` even exists. Use `fgets` to read whole lines as strings, make sure `fgets` returns a non-null pointer, and then use e.g. `sscanf` to attempt to parse the input. But again, always check what `sscanf` returns.

Comment: but the scanf is in other function...
i am trying to create a function that validates if the inputs of the scanf function is correct.

Comment: For best result regarding integer input validation, read the whole line (one `fgets` call might not be enough) and use `strtol` to both validate and convert the input (if it's valid).

Comment: @EraoS: If that "other function" which calls `scanf` ignores and discards the return value of the `scanf` function call, then afterwards, you have no way to restore this discarded information, so you have no way of telling whether the input was valid or not. Therefore, the only thing you can do is to ensure that the return value of `scanf` is not ignored.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` returns a value. You should check it. If you call `scanf` with a format string with four conversions, it will return four if it successfully read and assigned four items. Otherwise, it will return a different value.

Specifically, it returns `EOF` if some failure (including end-of-file) occurs before reading the first item. Otherwise, it returns the number of items that were assigned.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    int result = scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    if (result == 4)
        printf("All four numbers were read.\n");
    else if (result == EOF)
        printf("End of file or an input error occurred before any items were read.\n");
    else
        printf("%d items were read.\n", result);
}
```

From a comment:

> … but the `scanf` is in other function…

Restructure your code so the function where `scanf` is called either checks the result of `scanf` or records information for the rest of the program to use to determine which numbers were read.

Comment: but the scanf is in other function...
i am trying to create a function that validates if the inputs of the scanf function is correct.